# SF DEV401 Online Exam Registration: Start Time in GTM or Local?

Tags: dev401

I want to register for the DEV401 exam at the webassessor page. I am totally confused about what time should i select. Is it my local time (germany), gmt or something else? 
(i've choosen `Online proctored`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks and good luck - from all the answers I've seen you posting here you should have no problem with the exam!

Comment: All the best for your Exam.
Could you please help me with the procedure of preparing for the dev 401 exam,What all topics have you prepared? I'm planning to take up the exam end of this month.I would be greatly helped if you share up your preparation experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Online proctored exams have always started at local time for me. I'm in the UK, and this hasn't always been the same as GMT.

If you log in to WebAssessor, at the top there is a link to edit profile which shows what country you are in. I believe that this must be used to control the time of online appointments.

Good luck with the exam!